# A confuse about big Rudin's remark

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am confused about a remark made in Rudin's book RCA 10.10
The remark says that

> $2\pi$$Ind_\gamma(z)$ is the net increase in the imaginary part of $\lambda(t)$,as t runs from $\alpha$ to $\beta$,and this is the same as the net increase of the argument of $\gamma(t)-z$.If we divide this increase by $2\pi$,we obtain “the number of times that $\gamma$ winds around $z$”.

Where,$\gamma$ is a closed path,$$\lambda(t)=\int_\alpha^t \frac{\gamma’{s}} {\gamma(s)-z}ds$$,and $$Ind_\gamma(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\gamma’(s)}{\gamma(s)-z}ds$$.

*My confusion is that I don’t know the meaning of “net increase”.  And how can we obtain “the number of times that...”*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This belongs to the basics of complex analysis.

Consider two points $z_j\ne0$ $\>(j=0,1)$ near each other, e.g. in the same half plane $H$, and let $\gamma\subset H$ be a  path connecting $z_0$ with $z_1$. This (short) $\gamma$ does not wind around the origin. Then
$$\int_0^1{\gamma'(t)\over\gamma(t)}\>dt=\int_\gamma{dz\over z}=\log{|z_1|\over|z_0|}+i\>\Delta\phi\ ,$$
where $\phi$ is a polar angle valid around the place, and
$$\Delta\phi=\arg(z_1)-\arg(z_0)\ \in\>]{-\pi},\pi[$$
is the small increase of the polar angle along $\gamma$. This increase may of course be negative; at any rate it has only to do with the position of the $z_j\in H$.

If you now have a long closed $\gamma$ that  might wind a few times around the origin you can choose anchor points $z_j\in\gamma$ $\>(0\leq j\leq N, \>z_N=z_0)$. In this way $\gamma$ is partitioned into $N$ arcs $\gamma_j$ of the kind considered above, connecting $z_{j-1}$ with $z_j$. We now have
$$\int_\gamma{dz\over z}=\sum_j\int_{\gamma_j}{dz\over z}=\sum_j\log{|z_j|\over|z_{j-1}|}+i \sum_j(\Delta\phi)_{\gamma_j}=0+i \sum_j(\Delta\phi)_{\gamma_j}\ .$$
It turns out that $\int_\gamma{dz\over z}$ is $i$ times the sum of all small increases (decreases) of the polar angle along $\gamma$. This sum is $2\pi$ times the number ${\rm Ind}(\gamma,0)$ of positive windings of $\gamma$ around $0$, because each such winding increases the polar angle totally by $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much.However,what does the “net” mean?

Comment: @zik2019: I don't know. Maybe the author wanted to stress that he means the sum of all little increases and decreases of the polar angle, even when the curve is closed, so that the end polar angle seems to be the same as the starting polar angle.